# How to find entity using their associate's attribute in waterline sails.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Please help me My issue describe as follow 
1) User Entity

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

identity: 'user',
connection: 'local-postgresql',

attributes: {
firstName: 'string',
lastName: 'string',

// Add a reference to Pet
pet: {
  model: 'pet'
}
}
});
```

2) Pet Entity

```
var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

identity: 'pet',
connection: 'local-postgresql',

attributes: {
breed: 'string',
type: 'string',
name: 'string',

// Add a reference to User
user: {
  model: 'user'
}
}
});
```

These entities are associated with each other.
Now I want to find User entity using attribute of pet (i.e name).
How should be query for this situation ?
or any other way to join these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Pet's name = 'XXXXXX'

```
Pet.findAll().where({name:'XXXXXX'}).populate('user').exec(function(err, pet){
   user = pet.user
})
```